# Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе этажа выводилось номера кабинетов?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Задача:
Есть 4-этажное здание, на каждом этаже разное количество кабинетов. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе этажа выводилось номера кабинетов? Это можно сделать с помощью массива? Просьба показать небольшой пример! Спасибо!

Comment: Задача так же малоинформативна, как и заголовок...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двумерный массив подойдет, правда, куда вы хотите выводить и как, непонятно.

```
var building = [[101,102,103,104,105],
                [201,203,204,210,240,225,225],
                [301,302,303],
                [401,405,407,409,410,411,412,413]]
console.log(building[0]); //1-й этаж
console.log(building[1]); //2-й этаж
console.log(building[3]); //4-й этаж
```